# Matplotlib pgf backend returns "LaTeX returned an error, probably missing font or error in preamble" for all plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I've spent the last few hours trying to get PGF backend to work. I was trying to use xelatex, but it wouldn't run at all.

Now I have made this example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("pgf")
pgf_with_rc_fonts = {
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex"
}
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_rc_fonts)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,2.5))
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.savefig('figure.pgf')
```

which raises an error. I will get to that in a minute. However, the error disappears if I remove the plt.savefig('figure.pgf'). The output returned from the terminal is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dokumenter/fys2130/oblig4/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    plt.savefig('figure.pgf')
  File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 577, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1470, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2194, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 835, in print_pgf
    self._print_pgf_to_fh(fh, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 814, in _print_pgf_to_fh
    RendererPgf(self.figure, fh),
  File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 422, in __init__
    self.latexManager = LatexManagerFactory.get_latex_manager()
  File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 232, in get_latex_manager
    new_inst = LatexManager()
  File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 322, in __init__
    raise LatexError("LaTeX returned an error, probably missing font or error in preamble:\n%s" % stdout)
matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf.LatexError: LaTeX returned an error, probably missing font or error in preamble:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**---! /home/marius/.texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

My matplotlib version is 1.4.2.

My question is, how do I go about troubleshooting a problem like this?

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Which TeX distro are you using? MikTeX or TeXLive?

Comment: Your example works fine here. Matplotlib 1.4.2 (Python 3.4), TeX Live 2014, on Kubuntu. @percusse TeX Live 2012/Debian (see fourth last line in error block).

Comment: Not sure why this question got closed. Here's a similar one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52936063/2747160